# android development software using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm a new android developer and downloaded the "complete" Eclipse ADT with the Android SDK for Windows (64-bit). After I extracted the files, I tried running Eclipse and I got my first error message

> "A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must
>   be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was
>   found after searching the following locations:
>   C:/Apps/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/jre/bin/javaw.exe"
>   javaw.exe in your current PATH."

So my next step was trying to download the 64 bit "jdk-8uk-windows-x64" so that I could run Eclipse. I put the jdk file in different subdirectories including creating one in the jre/bin subdirectory and running Eclipse gave me the same error over and over no matter where the jdk file was.

Comment: Did you actually try *installing* the JDK? Just moving the downloaded file into place won't install the JDK.

Comment: go to command prompt and execute `java -version` . tell us what u get. You just downloaded and extracted the package. you didnt install it. There is a *x64.exe which is the JDK installer. Install JDK. Or set path to JRE location and then run the eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add your folder contains **javax.exe** to system variable **PATH** by right click on My computer --> Properties --> at Advanced tab, click to **Environment variable** button --> adding your java virtual machine directory to **PATH** variable

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you so much Dai - after trying this method, I edited the Path to include the location of the javax.exe file (at the front of the long string) and this worked!